# User Defined Function in Excel with Internet Explorer giving error because of time of fetch

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I am trying to create a user defined function in Excel VBA which will go to an e-commerce website (say https://www.woolworths.com) and fetch the product title of a particular product. I have created the complete code and if I debug it, it's working fine and giving me the data. The code I have created is as below:

```
Function function1() As Integer

Dim browser As Object
Dim htmlDoc As New htmlDocument
Dim productName As String

url = "https://www.woolworths.com.au/shop/productdetails/781394/red-rock-deli-share-pack-honey-soy-chicken"
Set browser = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
browser.Visible = True
browser.navigate url
Do Until browser.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 4))
Set htmlDoc = browser.document

'Get Product Name
productName = htmlDoc.getElementsByClassName("shelfProductTile-title heading3")(0).innerText

function1 = 5


End Function
```

Note:

1. Even though I said that I want product name, I have intentionally given the output as "5" just for testing purposes.
2. For the code to work, I will just change the function output as String as change "5" to productName

The problem is that when I try to use this function from the Excel file, it is giving me "#Value" error (attaching a snapshot in the end). But if I hide the line "productName = htmlDoc.getElementsByClassName("shelfProductTile-title heading3")(0).innerText", then it is working fine.
I guess this is something related to the speed of function working. Since the ie window opening takes time, the function might get expired or something. Please help me out here.

Snapshot of error:
[image]

Comment: VBA functions used in Excel sheets have some strict limitations, including NOT being able to "Set properties or execute most methods" (a little vague but its a direct quote from the MS doco website). When a function breaks these rules, the function returns #VALUE! It's quite possible that this limitation is triggering the error. Ref: https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/170787/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel

Comment: Btw ... I don't think that (generally) the time a function takes to return a value is an issue. I tested a function which didn't return for 30seconds and Excel had no issue with it.

Comment: Scraping is against terms and conditions. Also, if page is static using xhr would be better and tie it to a button push in sheet. That can write result to a specific cell and be triggered when you want. Alternatively, can be tied to a worksheet_change event

Comment: @QHarr I am just doing this for educational purposes. To understand how Programming in VBA works. Yes, as a workaround I have used a button for this but I don't understand why the function should not be working.

Comment: @TechnoDabbler I don't think I am setting and property or breaking any rule of functions here. Do you think I am?

Comment: To answer your question, yes I think your code breaks a rule of custom functions.The point wasn't setting properties, but calling the method. As the link says, a rule of custom functions is that they cannot "execute most methods". getElementsByClassName is a method. While nothing specifically says that it can't do that particular method, your testing shows that is doesn't work. And we know that when a function has an issue with a method, #VALUE! is the error shown. The approach suggested by @QHarr is reasonable ... so sounds like you have at least one way forward.

Comment: @TechnoDabbler Yes I think that can be the case. I have programmed it using a button now. Thanks a lot :)